# Yii2, Custom validation message with attribute names

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

In Login form, I need to have `glyphicon-remove` icon at the end of every validation message with the corresponding field names. So I used below code in the `Login model`.

```
['email', 'required', 'message' => 'Email cannot be blank<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>'],
['password', 'required', 'message' => 'Password cannot be blank<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>']
```

Instead of this above code, Is there any possible way to use something like the below code.

```
[['email', 'password'], 'required', 'message' => $attribute.' cannot be blank<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>']
```

The idea of the above code is to get corresponding field name dynamically for every fields.

Please do the needful. Thanks.

**Update**

The `HTML` code (`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>`) here I've used is output correctly by using `encode=>'false'`. But what I need is instead of defining separately for every fields, need to define commonly for all fields.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `{attribute}` in your message to reference the attribute name.

```
public function rules()
  {
    return [
      [
        ['email','password', 'password_verify', 'alias', 'fullname'],
        'required',
        'message' => '{attribute} is required'
      ],
      [['email'], 'email'],
      [['fullname'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
      [['password', 'password_verify'], 'string', 'min' => 8, 'max' => 20],
      [['password_verify'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],
  ];
}
```

You can also use the other options set in the validator like `{min}` or `{requiredValue}`

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I need. Thanks again for your answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your form:

*_form.php*

```
<?php
   $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
            'fieldConfig' => ['errorOptions' => ['encode' => false, 'class' => 'help-block']] 
   ]);
?>
```

`errorOptions` default encoding is true so, your html code is encoded as message, so it won't work until you set `'encode' => false`.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but I need something else. Could you please check my updated question. Thanks.